# Site Analytics privilege text outdated

Tags: bug

There should be two tabs: history and google analytics, according to https://security.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/site-analytics

Instead, I see history and traffic sources. The page title of traffic sources is (still?) google analytics. I assume the help text is outdated?

As an aside, it's also a bit of an anti-climax, thinking you get access to google analytics-level details of stats (I was already wondering about the privacy implications, but postponed judgement until I got to see what exactly was shared) and found only stats like "10% comes from duckduckgo and 8% from the law stackexchange site". I get the reason for it, but this does not even approximate GA, even if the source of the two datapoints you extract is GA.

Comment: As it says, "This tab gives you access to **select** Google Analytics data from the last 30 days."

Comment: Congrats on 25k! :-)